# how to delete a collection in mongodb which has space in between its name i.e.'Coimbatore Express'?

Tags: mongodb

this code will show the error am facing the collection which am trying to delete is 'Coimbatore Express' and problem is I have a space between Coimbatore & Express.

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi79u.png

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either try using a dot(`.`) operator to replace the space.

```
db.Coimbatore.Express.drop()
```

Or alternatively as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/mongo/#working-with-the-mongo-shell) use `getCollection` as:

```
db.getCollection("Coimbatore Express").drop()
```